# Angular 2 dialog in route guard candeactivate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, if there are unsaved pages in the route, I want a dialog to popup and ask if the user wishes for data to be saved or not or cancel completely.

I've tried to use prompt and confirm but those only let me have 2 buttons at once while I need 3 buttons to display the Yes, No, Cancel at the same time.

My problem is that while I can get the dialog to popup I don't know how to make Angular 2 wait for user selection before proceeding, I've tried it with both Javascript and Jquery, but still can't figure out how to make angular wait for the user input and then act on the selection.

All tips are welcome! :)

A little plunker here, click to bar, then foo then bar again to have the popup show up, not sure how to make it wait for the value in the same time as now it just uses the previous value that was set

```
    if (target.hasBeenChanged == true) {

        target.popuptest();
        // using the last one set in component for now
        let selection = target.popupchoice;

        console.log('selected was: ' + selection);


        if (selection == 'yes') {
            target.PushToSave();
            return true;
        } else if (selection == 'no') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/so7KeiaMiqbSy7Nr5nSB?p=info

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own HTML and CSS to have a `div` which will act as a popup. There are [very good tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)s about this. You will show/hide the popup whenever you wish and you can add your own tags there, including the buttons. Then, you might want a `function` which will receive an input according to the action which was done by the user and add the function call with the right parameter to the onclick of your buttons.

Comment: Yup! that's exactly what I'm doing, I made a mini popup and it works fine, but the problem is when I try to run timed things.

For example when I ask the deactivate guard to check for the value, it instantly opens the popup, but there is no function for it to actually wait for the user to press a button, it just goes on evaluating all the variables that get returned as undefined because user has not made an input yet

Comment: @D.Newbie you can check for the values using a helper function you write yourself. If you need a waiting logic, you might have a request and you might want to put the code which opens the popup inside its callback.

Comment: Yeah, it must be somewhere along the lines, I have all the needed code for opening the popup and also closing it afterwards but what's missing is exactly the wait function that would wait for user to select an option and the option to be put in a string which can be used to decide where to route and to call the save function or not, I'll look into the callbacks and try to figure something out :)

Comment: @D.Newbie in this case you will need to create an event handler for changing the value of that tag. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Here's a mini plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/so7KeiaMiqbSy7Nr5nSB?p=preview , for some reason it only works after clicking bar then foo then bar again, but still shows weird thing I cannot figure out just yet